# Formatting an Access field of strings into times

Tags: ms-access, time

If I have a field of strings in `HH:MM` format, how do I convert that field into a field that is in time format? The only thing I could find was the DateValue format and examples of how to output the same datetime for every row, and the CAST function, which I could not get to work.

In case that is not clear enough, the data in this field looks like:

```
16:32
05:15
19:20
```

All in string format. I want this into time format.

Comment: Try TimeValue() function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/functions-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: _I want this into time format._ That's what you have. You mean _time value_ - as shown by @June7.